# Data is shown in table format but not systematically?

Tags: php

Html content is  in separate files. and then I have included those files in php files.

**Here Problem** is that data is not coming under their respective headings i.e.,
EmployeeID,EmployeeName,MobileNumber are coming under "Mobilenumber" heading.

**Header File :**

```
 <div class="row" style="height:370px; width:850px; overflow:scroll;">
<table border ='1' align = "center" id="FormTable" class="table"  >
    <tr>
        <th> Employee Code
        <th> Employee Name
        <th> Mobile Number
    <tr>
        <td>
        <td>
        <td>
```

**Footer File :**

```
</th>
</th>
</th>
</tr>
</td>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**Main file :**

```
public function showEmployeeProfile() {
        if (!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["passwrd"])) {
            header("Location:index.php");
            // Cannot Access this page without Login.
        }
        if (empty($_POST)) {
             if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
                echo '<h3>' . "Welcome &nbsp '{$_SESSION['email']}'" . '</h3>';
                // Prints Email ID of the HR Manager.
            }

        echo '<h4>'.'<center>'."Profile Info of the Employees".'</center>'.'</h4>'.'<br/>';
        $read_sql = "select * from employeeprofile";
        $result_fetch = mysqli_query($this->connection, $read_sql);
        include ("Header.php");
        while ($resultArr = $result_fetch->fetch_array()) {
            echo $resultArr['EmployeeId'] . '<br/>';
            echo $resultArr['EmployeeName'] . '<br/>';
            echo $resultArr['MobileNumber'] . '<br/>' . '<hr/>';
        }
         include ("Footer.php");
    }
}
```

> ***I Think changes needs to be done in header and footer files.***

Comment: You are not echoing the data into a table row in <td> elements! So it wont appear in the table correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make corrections in all three of your files.

In your header:

```
<tr>
    <th>Employee Code</th>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Mobile Number</th>
</tr>
```

In your footer, remove everything before `</table>`.

In your `while()` loop:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $resultArr['EmployeeId'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $resultArr['EmployeeName'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $resultArr['MobileNumber'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```